# Undefined collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to Javascript and Backbone and maybe it is a stupid question. I have this Collection

```
define(['backbone', 'models/profile'], function(Backbone, Profile) {

  // Collection definition
  var Profiles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/profile',
    model: Profile,
    //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('Profiles'),

    initialize: function() {    
        this.fetch();

        if (this.isEmpty() || !this.where({is_guest: true}))
            this.create({name: 'Guest', is_guest: true, has_pin: false});
     }
  });

  return Profiles;

});
```

I want to add items to this collection from the console in the chrome, I tried
`collection.create({name: 'Guest', is_guest: true, has_pin: false});` and `Profiles.create({name: 'Guest', is_guest: true, has_pin: false});` but it says that it is undefined. Can someone explain me why, or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

check the context using this in the browser and check if collection object is in scope yet or not. Simply typing collection in console won't work. Or provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scope issue as well to me as code looks OK (well you're calling fetch() in the constructor asynchronously, so you're isEmpty() is likely to fail...but that's a different issue). You're using AMD/Require.js so please provide the code for the module that's loading this collection in as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that `Profiles` is only in the scope of your file above and you cant access it from outside. Since you are using `Profiles.create({...` I assume you havent initialised the collection.

Just a hint:

file 1: your collection from above

file 2:

```
define(['collections/my_collection_from_above'], function(MyCollectionFromAbove) {
    var myCollection = new MyCollectionFromAbove();
    myCollection.create({....});
});
```

or another case:

```
var MyCollectionFromAbove = require('collections/my_collection_from_above');
var myCollection = new MyCollectionFromAbove();
myCollection.create({....});
```

Of course... I am just guessing what you are trying to do.